# How do I copy binary data to a stringstream

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `std::vector<int>` and I want serialize it. For this purpose I am trying to use a `std::stringstream`

```
 vector<int> v;
 v.resize(10);
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
 v[i]=i;


 stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out |stringstream::binary);
```

However when I copy the vector to the stringstream this copy it as character

```
ostream_iterator<int> it(ss);
copy(v.begin(),v.end(),it);
```

the value that inserted to buffer(_Strbuf) is "123456789"

I sucssesed to write a workaround solution

```
for (int i=1;i<10;i++)
   ss.write((char*)&p[i],sizeof(int));
```

I want to do it something like first way by using std function like copy

thanks Herzl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, this is your workaround but it may be used with std::copy() algorithm.

```
   template<class T>
   struct serialize
   {
      serialize(const T & i_value) : value(i_value) {}
      T value;
   };

   template<class T>
   ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const serialize<T> & obj)
   {
      os.write((char*)&obj.value,sizeof(T));
      return os;
   }
```

Usage

```
ostream_iterator<serialize<int> > it(ss);
copy(v.begin(),v.end(),it);
```

Comment: I like this approach in general, but it is often an error to blindly output memory like this.  You still need to write something that can properly serialize each type.

Comment: Completely agree. I would never use such code in production. I would prefer above-mentioned "for" cycle :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not an answer to your problem, but if you are not limited to the STL you could try ([boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)) or [google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Boost even has build-in support for de-/serializing STL containers (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl)

Comment: thanks omer but
I need connect to a hardware 
and as I see boost add some control data to the data(type of classed)

Answer (score 1):

To use std::copy with ostream::write, you'd need to write your own output iterator that knows how to correctly serialize the type.  That said, I'm not sure what you expect to gain from this approach, but [here's a first pass](http://codepad.org/oYqPiMej) at that for an example:

```
struct ostream_write_int
  : std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, int, void, void, void>
{
  std::ostream *s;
  ostream_write_int(std::ostream &s) : s (&s) {}

  ostream_write_int& operator++() { return *this; }
  ostream_write_int& operator++(int) { return *this; }
  ostream_write_int& operator*() { return *this; }

  void operator=(int x) {
    s->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));
  }
};
```

This could be templated only if you defer the serialization logic to some other function (as the formatted stream iterators do to operator<<).

Answer (score 1):

Like Fred, I don't see the point of this, what you are effectively trying to do is:

```
ss.rdbuf()->sputn(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v[0]), sizeof(int) * v.size());
```

Comment: This is not very readable. I would never understand such code easily.

Comment: @the_drow, "never" is a long time! ;), you can replace `.rdbuf()->sputn(` with `.write(` if you want, it's the same thing..

Comment: This is true for the case of a vector, but an iterator which writes each item (as in mine or Stas's answers) can be used with any input iterators, such as from a std::list.

Comment: @Nim: I didn't say that I would never understand that code. I said that this kind of code cannot be read easily. It took me two seconds to figure it out.

Comment: @the_drow: Welcome to C++. :)  @Nim: I didn't point out what I really meant.  What you point out is only a special case for a very specific circumstance which, I suspect, is only used as an example in the question rather than being the entire scope.  For example, in addition to a different container, the serialization will be different for other types, or even just for an int when using htonl.

Comment: @FredNurk: I am not new to C++. You just don't do those stuff unless you have a really good reason to do so and then you should leave a comment.

Comment: @Fred, again, I agree, all I offered is the effective case (i.e. whether you copy the array one by one or all as one), both your code and mine does the same thing (given it's a vector of ints). Yours is more flexible (can support different containers, types, endian etc.), mine caters for a specific need. It's up to the OP to be smart enough to realise what to use when...

Comment: @Nim: Okay, maybe that's the root of my confusion here: the question is about how to use std::copy, not about how to write a vector; and your answer only is about the latter instead of the former.

Comment: This solution does not work with the cereal (serialization) library, nor any rdbuf() solution. For some reason I have to create a string and pass in the c_str() and length and then construct the stringstream with that.